# Rendering three-composition raster map with ternary colormap using R

Tags: raster, r, cartography, spatial-statistics, visualisation

Say there are three raster maps, representing percentages of sand, silt and clay respectively. The three values for each cell are hence summed up to 1. I want to use one raster map to characterize the relative contribution of the three materials. I found an R package named 'tricolore' for this purpose, but it is for a vector map, like this:

[image]

but my compositional data are stored in raster format.

The following is a simulation study in R:

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(0)
sim.sand <- matrix(runif(100, 0, 0.5), nrow = 10)
sim.silt <- matrix(runif(100, 0, 0.5), nrow = 10)
sim.total <- matrix(1, 10, 10)

sim.clay <- sim.total - sim.sand - sim.silt
```

How can I visualize the raster compositions of each cell using R?

Comment: Are you trying to do this using R or something else?  You have a tag for the Spatial Analyst extension to ArcGIS Desktop.  Are you perhaps using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: Combine the 3 rasters into a single 3 band raster, symbolize as RGB in QGIS or ArcGIS. Like [this example](https://i.imgur.com/zP0Ix7J.png) for fractional cover rasters.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thank you. I know ArcMap can help visualize data with three bands via RGB color image. But I want other three selected colors as the end color members, just as the vector case in 'tricolore'.

Comment: @user2856 How was the map in this case created, especially the ternary map, and how was the values retrieved for rendering the map?

Comment: I’ve focused your question on R to get it re-opened. If you want to also ask about other GIS software then do so in a separate question so that you can describe what you’ve tried with that particular software there.

Comment: @emberbillow It's just a 3 band raster symbolized as RGB.

Comment: have you solved this issue? If so, could you share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package 'raster' to convert your matrices to rasters, stack them, and plot in RGB, such as:

```
library(raster)

sand_ras <- raster(sim.sand)
silt_ras <- raster(sim.silt)
clay_ras <- raster(sim.clay)

bands <- c(sand_ras, silt_ras, clay_ras)

soil_stack <- stack(bands)

plot(sand_ras)

plotRGB(soil_stack)
```

output:

[image]

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out a simple way to customize the colors of the channels or create a nice legend like the example you gave. A more beautiful solution is probably more attainable using 'ggplot2'.